# truffle test does not run tests when test network is not specified

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

trying to run a test for my contract, but truffle test is  just compiling the contracts and not running anything. my truffle.config does not specify a test network, which should result in truffle spawning a ganache instance when i run truffle test. Instead, I am getting the following:

[image]

and no further output.

here are the versions I'm using:

- Truffle v5.5.19 (core: 5.5.19)
- Ganache v7.2.0
- Solidity - 0.8.9(solc-js)
- Node v14.19.3
- Web3.js v1.5.3

When I specify a network in truffle-config it works, but why isn't it creating its own ganache instance if I don't specify?

here is my truffle-config.js:
[image]

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: can you show your truffle-config.js file pls

Comment: @sola24 edited to include truffle-config.js

Comment: actually ... I mostly use hardhat but when I have used truffle I ran up the ganache blockchain independently/in advance, either with ganache-cli or the ganache gui version

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because inside the truffle -config file the truffle will recognise the default network and the solc compiler version, and you need to edit it according to your requirement!